# Initializing a pthread mutex in shared memory

Tags: mutex, shared-memory

I can initialize a mutex in static memory with an initializer:

```
pthread_mutex_t mymutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
```

but how do I initialize one in shared memory where I have to allocate the memory separately from initializing the variable? Can I do a memcpy()?

```
pthread_mutex_t mymutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
memcpy(&globalmutex, &mymutex, sizeof(mymutex);
```

I thought I remembered reading a long time ago that when allocating a mutex into memory guaranteed to be initialized to zero's, it doesn't need initialization--intended for exactly this case--but I can't find that written down anywhere. Is that really true?--I notice that PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER is defined as  { { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, { 0, 0 } } } on my redhat system.

Answer (score 4):

You need to be careful here, not all implementations support mutexes that can work across processes.

PThreads itself supports this by use of the process shared attribute but, if you want that, you won't be using the default initialiser.

Instead you'll need to use `pthread_mutex_init()` after properly constructing a mutex attribute structure:

```
int pthread_mutex_init(
    pthread_mutex_t *mutex,
    const pthread_mutexattr_t *attr);
```

Best bet would be to just allocate space in shared memory then cast it to the correct type and pass it to the `init` function. I think that may be safer than copying it after the initialisation.

Comment: If I do that, how do I prevent each processes from initializing the mutext?

PROCESS 1: Initialize;
PROCESS 1: LOCK;
PROCESS 2: Initialize; and I'm toast.

Comment: @John, this is exactly the same problem if you have threads init the mutex (rather than `main` before the threads are created). I have a question. What resource are you trying to protect across processes? There may be another way.

Comment: I use PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER to guarantee that my mutex is initialized only one time before any processing begins. I am writing CUDA (GPU processing) code that may be running in multiple processes at the same time, and I want to protect blocks of CudaMallocs with a lock so a processes gets all it's memory if it's available. I don't want three processes to fail--each with 40% of the required memory.

Comment: I would think about setting up the shared memory mutex in one of your processes then having it start the other two (if possible). As I said, even if your pthreads implementation supports cross-process mutexes, the default state is process-private so I'm pretty sure you _can't_ use PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't control the process start up.

Comment: Sorry, @John, that's about as much as I can help out then. I know of no way to get workable cross-process mutexes while using the default initialiser since it needs a mutex attribute. The only possibility I could suggest looking into is a non-pthread sync primitive between the processes but I don't know enough about your target environment to assist further.

Comment: You didn't exactly answer the question, but I voted you're answer up because you provoked me into reconsidering the correctness of the our overall system architecture.

Comment: @JohnGordon: If you cannot guarantee pthread_init() to initialize only once, then probably you could not guarantee the memcpy() being called only once, neither.

Comment: You can always use a flag in shared memory telling if the pthread mutex has been initialized. And protect it - and initialization - with a spinlock also using shared memory.

Answer (score 4):

I have a similar problem and one approach I'm using is try to exclusively create the shared memory with `(O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_EXCL)`. If the creation succeeds, initialize the mutex in shared memory. If it failed, check if the shared memory already exists. If the shared memory exists, just open it with the flag `O_RDWR` and map to your mutex but assume it was already initialized by the process that successfully created it. Here's a bit of pseudo-code (POSIX + pthreads):

```c
/* semaphore POST (block access from other processes) */
/* try to exclusively create */
int fd = shm_open (name, (O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_EXCL), (S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR));
if (fd == -1) {
    /* failed creation */
    /* semaphore WAIT (wait until mutex initialized) */
    if (errno == EEXIST) {
        /* already exists, try to open */
        fd = shm_open (name, O_RDWR, (S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR));
        if (fd == -1) {
            /* check errors */
        } else {
            /* optionally check shared data size with fstat */
            fstat () ...
            /* map */
            mmap () ...
        }
    } else {
        /* check create errors */
    }
} else {
    /* successful creation! */
    /* truncate */
    ftruncate () ...
    /* map */
    mmap () ...
    /* initialize mutex */
    pthread_mutexattr_init () ...
    pthread_mutexattr_setpshared ( ... , PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED ) ...
    pthread_mutex_init () ...
    /* semaphore WAIT (wait until all processes are finished) */
}
```

A problem with this method is that there may be a race condition where another process opens it and attempts to lock the mutex immediately after the shared memory was created but before the mutex was initialized. I've never tried to test this scenario (it would be difficult to achieve) - I'm not working with a system that pushes those kinds of limits. However, a semaphore may be helpful in this situation to block access until the mutex is created. I added the semaphore logic in comments, but I'd appreciate feedback on it (the semaphores are not implemented or tested).

### Edit

After a bit of thought, I realize the IPC semaphore guard may be better as a mutex and then we have to create a shared memory mutex recursively haha. But seriously, having a single process that solely manages the the creation, initialization, and destruction of a guard mutex could work.

Comment: I think that your approach will work nicely if process startup is timed/coordinated systematically.

A variant of this in a system I support has a single process dedicated as the allocator and the readers all establish interprocess communications - using OS-provided messaging features - prior to attempting to map the shared memory.  As the allocator allocates before beginning to respond to messages, the response to any message tells the mappers that the memory should be available.

Comment: @sage Thank you for your comment, I have since changed my approach to have a dedicated allocator/supervisor process to manage shared memory in the way you describe. It is the best way to ensure reliable race-free and safe IPC mapping.