# fork and exec with respect to locking shared memory - C

Tags: c, multithreading, exec, posix, fork

So I'm just wondering if I had a simple task to do in concurrency, how would I do this with multiple processes using fork() and exec() from a parent process, while locking some aspects of the parent process' memory (so that they don't overwrite each other), but making it available to those processes later?

I know I can do this with POSIX threads with their mutex locks, but what's the process equivalent to that? Is there a way to "lock" shared memory amongst threads? And then would I have to "wait()" for the other threads to finish those locked areas of memory before the other threads could access it?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the pthreads implementation of mutexes, you would still use them to synchronize between processes... you would place them in shared memory. [Initializing a pthread mutex in shared memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068974/initializing-a-pthread-mutex-in-shared-memory) addresses this.

You can also use a simple pipe to synchronize access -- pre-fill the pipe with a token and require a successful read of the token to permit resource access. Then write the token back into the pipe in order to release the resource.

Answer (score 0):

First: if you call `exec` and it succeeds then your process image will be overwritten. You will loose any shared memory and you will need to set it up with your favourite shared memory paradigm (e.g. posix shared memory `shm_open`).

If you `fork` then any memory that was mapped shared will remain shared. Means you can place your favourite mutex (e.g. `pthread_mutex_t`, `sem_t`) into it and use it with the standard functions that go with it.

```
void * shared_memory = mmap(
      NULL // anywhere
    , sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE) // mmap only works in chunks of pages
                            // typically 0x1000
    , PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE // read-write
    , MAP_SHARED    // shared
    | MAP_ANONYMOUS // anonymous, non-file backed
    #ifdef MAP_HASSEMAPHORE
    | MAP_HASSEMAPHORE  // OS X requires this flag in case you
                        // intend to have semaphores in that segment
    #endif
    , -1 // no file backing
    , 0
    );

if (shared_memory == MAP_FAILED) {
    perror("mmap");
    abort();
}

// we use that memory to place a mutex tehre
pthread_mutex_t * mutex = shared_memory;

pthread_mutex_init(mutex, NULL);

pid_t pid = fork();

if (pid < 0) {
    perror("fork");
    abort();
}

if (!pid) {
    // child goes here
    // use the mutex here
} else {
    // parent goes here
    // use the mutex here
}
```

Comment: Shared memory is given a name in the case of `shm_open()` and an identifier which can be constant in the case of `shmget()`; both of these allow an `exec` process to use the same region without difficulty.`mmap()` would not normally be used for implementing shared memory (unless the shared memory were mapped bytes of a file, though that would have unnecessary overhead).

Comment: @mah what I meant is that when you call `exec` all existing mappings are unmapped and you have to remap shared memory in the new process. When forking I prefer to use anonymous shared memory.

Comment: I see you're thinking that because you're thinking of using `mmap()` for the sharing mechanism... please read the edit I made to my comment at the same time you were commenting.