# Printf causes deadlock.. but why?

Tags: c, printf, locking, mutex, deadlock

I was messing around with mutexes in C and found that the following program eventually deadlocks in the parent process if and only if there is a call to `printf` within the critical section in the child process (between the lock/unlock function calls).

The program allocates 256 bytes of shared memory, then it initializes a mutex within it, after that it spawns a child process and reads and writes the first `sizeof(int)` bytes of shared memory and print its content.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>


int main(){
    pthread_mutex_t *lock;
    int *shared_memory = mmap(NULL, 0x100, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_SHARED, 0, 0);
    if (shared_memory == MAP_FAILED) {
        printf("Error in mapping memory!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    lock = (pthread_mutex_t *)shared_memory + sizeof(int);
    if ( pthread_mutex_init(lock, NULL) != 0) {
        printf("Error in initializing mutex\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    int pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1) {
        printf("Error in fork()!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else if (pid == 0) {
        unsigned int val = 0xC0FFE, j = 0;
        while (j < 3) {
            pthread_mutex_lock(lock);
            printf("%p: %08x\n",shared_memory, *shared_memory);
            *shared_memory = val;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(lock);
            j++;
            val++;
        }
    }
    else {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 30) {
            pthread_mutex_lock(lock);
            *shared_memory-=1;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(lock);
            printf("%p: %08x\n",shared_memory, *shared_memory);
            i++;
        }
        while(wait(NULL) > 0);
    }

}
```

Any idea why the printf causes deadlock when placed in the critical section in the parent process?

GDB confirms the program is stuck in waiting in a call to `pthread_mutex_lock` in the parent.

```bash
gdb -p `pidof ./test`
...
futex_wait (private=0, expected=2, futex_word=0x7f13ba8be0a0) at ../sysdeps/nptl/futex-internal.h:146
146 ../sysdeps/nptl/futex-internal.h: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt 10
#0  futex_wait (private=0, expected=2, futex_word=0x7f13ba8be0a0) at ../sysdeps/nptl/futex-internal.h:146
#1  __GI___lll_lock_wait (futex=futex@entry=0x7f13ba8be0a0, private=0) at ./nptl/lowlevellock.c:49
#2  0x00007f13ba6dd082 in lll_mutex_lock_optimized (mutex=0x7f13ba8be0a0) at ./nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c:48
#3  ___pthread_mutex_lock (mutex=0x7f13ba8be0a0) at ./nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c:93
#4  0x000055e3eca8d37e in main () at test.c:44
```

**SOLUTION/ANSWER: Adding `PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED` as mutex attribute solved the problem!**

Comment: I think you managed to break the mutex somehow. Maybe you need to set it to `PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068974/initializing-a-pthread-mutex-in-shared-memory

Comment: `lock = (pthread_mutex_t *)shared_memory + sizeof(int)` is looking suspicious. It's really adding `sizeof(int) * sizeof(pthread_mutex_t)`, which could be going out of the bounds of the shared region depending on the size of the struct.

Comment: Setting the mutex attribute using `PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED` solved the problem. Thanks @teapot418